# Buffered Reader

Tags: java, файлы

считываю информацию из файла, после этого агрегирую её и записываю в отдельные файлы. Однако при записи возникает проблема, почему-то программа считывает информацию через строку. т.е. 2, 4, 6 и т.д. строки записываются в файл, а 1, 3, 5 и т.д. не пишутся.
Код:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:\\0\\15k.txt"));
        int i = 0;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\0\\1\\" + i + ".txt"));
        while(br.readLine() != null) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s != null) {
                String answer = "агрегация";
                bw.write(answer);
                i++;
                bw.close();
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("c:\\0\\1\\" + i + ".txt"));
            }
        }
        br.close();

    }

}
```

[image: Файл, из которого произвожу считывание]

что я делаю не так?

Comment: Когда ты делаешь проверку `while(br.readLine() != null)`, ты читаешь строку, а следовательно при вызове метода `readLine()` в теле цикла ты будешь читать уже следующую строку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы читаете две строки на каждую итерацию цикла.

> while(br.**readLine**() != null) {
>
> String s = br.**readLine**();

Исправить можно так:

```
String tmp;
while((tmp = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String s = tmp;
}
```